# Booting time is 1min 20 sec,how to make it faster?

Tags: boot, time

Ubuntu on my laptop takes 1min 20 seconds to load and it takes 10 seconds to load desktop icons.
Could you guys give me some tips to make it faster.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Run this to see whose causing you so much pain `systemd-analyze blame` and if not essential service stop it running at boot

Comment: Also please [edit] your question and, when adding the result requested above, take the time to post hardware specs and Ubuntu release/version as well.